# Exercise 4.4 in Brezis 'Functional Analysis' , $L^{p}$ functions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I have exercise 4.4 from Haim Brezis's book:

Let $f_{1},\dots,f_{k}$ be $k$ functions such that $f_{i}\in L^{p_{i}}(\Omega)$ whit $1\leq p_{i}\leq\infty$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,k\}$, and $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}p_{i}\leq1$. Set
\begin{equation*}
    f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{k}f_{i}(x)
\end{equation*}
Prove that $f\in L^{p}(\Omega)$ with $\frac{1}{p}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}=\frac{1}{p_{i}}$.

I tried to reason by induction from $ k = 2 $ as the author's indication says, but in inductive step I have $g(x)=f(x)f_{k+1}(x)$ with $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{k}f_{i}(x)$, I would like to see what

\begin{equation*}
    \|g\|_{p} \leq \|f\|_{a} \|f_{k+1}\|_{p_{k+1}}, \text{whit } 1\leq a \leq\infty
\end{equation*}
for $p$ such that $\frac{1}{p}=\sum_{1}^{k}\frac{1}{p_{i}}\leq 1$ and $1
=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{p_{i}}$ for conclude that $g\in L^{p}$.

Could you give me any ideas on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Are you familiar with Hölder's inequality?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how to use it, since with it I get a norm of style $\|\cdot\|_{1}$ from conjugates

Comment: You my use $\frac{p_{k+1}}{(1-p_{k+1})}\sum^k_{j=1}\frac{1}{p_j}=1$

Comment: Thanks! I will solve the problem from this idea

Comment: @MATorres: $a$ is not arbitrary. It is in fact the connect conjugate of $p_{k+1}$. Notice that $1=\Big(\sum^k_{j=1}\frac{1}{p_j}\Big) +\frac{1}{p_{k+1}}=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p_{k+1}}$ in your notation.

Comment: [This part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder%27s_inequality#Generalization_of_Hölder's_inequality) of Wikipedia's article related to Holder's inequality has a proof of the statement in which you are interested. Also,  there  is an  answer to a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2528528/121671) similar to yours that may be what you need. If you have further questions about this, let me know and I'll post something.

Comment: @MATorres: do you still have problems with this?

Comment: @OliverDiaz: Hi! I managed to solve it. Your indication helped me and also prove that if for $ 1 \leq p, q, r <\infty $ such that $ 1 / r = 1 / p + 1 / q $, they fulfill a Hölder type inequality. Thank you very much for the indication

Comment: @MATorres: brilliant! Do you mind if we closed your question? There are many duplicates to the "generalized" Holder's inequality and for management purposes, I may ask the moderators to close and merge this question with of the previous postings that  has already good answers. That will not affect your reputation of course.

Comment: @OliverDiaz: Excellent, no problem. As I am beginning to participate in the community, I still do not handle that very well.

Comment: Nothing to worry about. Closing a question because of duplication is not a bad thing. If somebody votes to close you are notifies with a message that says something along the lines of "does this answer LINK your question?. If it does, you may say yes and end of story, if the answers there are not clear to you, you may say NO and a reason why. That will start some discussion for others to help.

Comment: I understand, it seems quite practical, so the content is kept in order.